# Ajax POST to nodejs gives blank object

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js

I am trying to successfully ping an object back and forth from the browser to a nodejs server via AJAX POST. However, I am having no luck, as the middleman from browser to server interprets the object as blank ( `{}` ). Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

**Client:**

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "/save");
xhr.onload = function(){
    console.log(xhr.responseText); //See what the server ponged
}
xhr.send({"foo": "bar"}); //Ping the object
```

**Server:**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.configure(function() {
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
  app.use(app.router);
});
app.configure('development', function() {
  app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true }));
});

app.configure('production', function() {
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
});

app.post('/save', function(req, res){  //When server receives ping
    res.send(req.body);    // Pong the object back
});

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

var server = app.listen(port);
```

Thanks

Comment: If this is Express 4, then many of the middleware were separated out and you will have to install them via npm (e.g. 'body-parser'). It should be noted that the 'body-parser' middleware is a special case because it no longer supports multipart forms if you are/were using that.

Comment: Maybe you need to JSON encode it.

Comment: I have tried JSON encoding. Also I have already run the npm install command..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is kind of hacky but works:

do this on your client side:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "/save");
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xhr.onload = function(){
    console.log(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)); //See what the server ponged
}
xhr.send('{"foo":"bar"}');
```

and on the server side send this:

```
res.send(Object.keys(req.body));
```

kind of hacky but worked for me :)

hope this helps you :)

Comment: Thanks :D guess theres no better way to do it?